# how to bulk insert content to every post in database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, function, mysql-workbench

I have a WordPress website with 2000 posts.
I need all the posts content to be updated with the title of the post at the end of the content.

For example ,the Post Titles

1. **"Google Vs Amazon",**
2. **"Mturk",**
3. **"Cotton Shirts".,etc**

The contents are:

1. **"These 2 companies....",**
2. **"Its a freelancing work...",**
3. **"Shirts are stitched with fabric..", respectively.**

The respective titles are to be added at the end of each post content. 
But I don't want them generated each time the post is loaded, Instead I want the actual content to be updated like that. Preferably Mysql operation.

Comment: you asked a bad question. please describe exactly what you want by an example. 
if you can provide some sample code it will helpful to answer correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 

here you can read about how to ask good questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not asked a clear question but anyway as I understand you need some filters to change post content.

here is a sample code to add **post title** to post content.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_post_title_to_content' );

//the function that add filter to the_content have to use one variable. 
function add_post_title_to_content( $content ) {

    // here we check if it is in single post or main query. so this will not apply to other positions like feeds.
    if ( is_single() || in_the_loop() || is_main_query() ) {

       return get_the_title().$content;
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: if you want title to be add at the end change my code on return. `return $content.' '.get_the_title();`

Comment: i forgot to notify that you have to add code in your **functions.php** file in active theme

Comment: Will this update the post content ?. or generate this content each time the post is viewed.?

Comment: it not update content. generates every time post views. if you want to update content you have to do other actions.